# what is the issue in this android counter

Tags: android

i am making a counter.
i did this coding for it, but it not working, i tried it in many other ways but not getting success. what problem i am creating here
code for the main activity is below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button add;
Button reset;
TextView count;
int counter=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);
    count=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        counter++;
        count.setText(counter);

        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        //count.setText("0000");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}



}
```

My xml coding is as below

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="00000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="120dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="138dp"
    android:text="ADD"
    android:textSize="80dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:text="RESET"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the issue in this android counter? you have to tell the issue.  ask ur problem

Comment: you need to read the documentation for TextView.setText(int)

Comment: when i click on add, its not increment, but i think all coding is correct

Comment: you are using setText(int) that looks up for a String in the resources. If this string can not be found the ResourceNotFoundException is throwned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

counter is a integer type so you need to use

```
count.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
```

instead of this

```
count.setText(counter);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here

`count.setText(counter);`

counter is an int, Use `count.setText(Integer.toString(counter));`

Answer (score 4):

You should set :

```
 count.setText(""+counter);
```

Instead of :

```
 count.setText(counter);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the integer.

```
count.setText(""+counter);
```

To set it to zero, `count.setText("0000");` looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `setOnClickListener()` for you count `Textview`

Add this statement in your `onCreate()` method

> count.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: The code above tries to set the text in `count` textview but it does not have any `onClickListener` registered to handle the click event. by using the `setOnClickListener()` statement one can register for click events

Comment: It is Icrementing the counter on Button Click as per the Code

Answer (score 2):

`public final void setText (int resid)`  -- the integer is a resource id. Use `""+counter`